# C++ Error in compiling due to pointer class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, aggregation

My code doesn't compile when I try running it. I get so many errors that I don't understand why those errors pop up in the first place. Some of the errors involve my header file. Some of the errors say that I'm missing ';' before '*' in my header file. Furthermore it says int assumed in my header file I will comment in my code where that happens.

This is the error im getting from the compiler:

```
 1`>\\csupdatevm\labusers\uuu_uuuuu\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\expection\expection\game_implementation.cpp(25): error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression`
```

In my header file I have:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>

    using namespace std;
    //#include <exception>

class Board{
    public:
        void displayBoard();
        void createBoard();
        void insert(int temp_move, char temp_player);
        bool isLegal(int move);
        vector<char> getBoard();
    private:
        const int NUM_SQUARES = 9;
        vector<char> board;
    };

    class Abstractplayer{
    public:
        int virtual move(char temp_player) = 0;
        char virtual selectPiece()=0;
        char askYesNo(string question);
        int askNumber(string question, int high, int low = 0);
        char winner(vector<char> const & another__temp_board);
    protected:
        char go_first;
        bool first_turn = true;
        char human;
        char computer;
        const char X = 'X';
        const char O = 'O';
        const char EMPTY = ' ';
        const char TIE = 'T';
        const char NO_ONE = 'N';
        Board another_board;

    };

    class Human:public Abstractplayer{
    public:
        int move(char temp_player);
        char selectPiece();
    };

    class Computer:public Abstractplayer{
    public:
        int move(char temp_player);
        char selectPiece();
    };

class Game{
    public:
        void play();
        void instructions();
        void announceWinner(char winner, char computer, char human);
    private:
        Human* Human;//error
        Computer* cpu;//error
        Board board;
        char turn = 'X';
        int move;
    };
```

In my human cpp file I have:

```
#include "tictactoe.h"


char Human::selectPiece()
{

    if (first_turn == true)
    {
        go_first = askYesNo("Do you require the first move?");

        if (go_first == 'y')
        {
            cout << "\nThen take the first move.  You will need it.\n";
            return 'X';
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nYour bravery will be your undoing... I will go first.\n";
            return 'O';
        }
        first_turn = false;
    }

    else
        return 'X';

}

int Human::move(char temp_player)
{
    int move = askNumber("Where will you move?", 9);
    while (!another_board.isLegal(move))
    {
        cout << "\nThat square is already occupied, foolish human.\n";
        move = askNumber("Where will you move?", 9);
    }
    cout << "Fine...\n";
    return move;
}
```

In my computer cpp file I have:

```
#include "tictactoe.h"

char Computer::selectPiece()
{
    return 'O';
}

int Computer::move(char temp_player)
{
    cout << "I shall take square number ";

    vector<char> temp_board_yo=another_board.getBoard();

    // if computer can win on next move, make that move
    for (int move = 0; move < 9; ++move)
    {
        if (another_board.isLegal(move))
        {
            temp_board_yo[move] = computer;
            if (winner(temp_board_yo) == computer)
            {
                cout << move << endl;
                return move;
            }
            // done checking this move, undo it
            temp_board_yo[move] = EMPTY;
        }
    }

    // if human can win on next move, block that move
    char human = 'X';
    for (int move = 0; move < 9; ++move)
    {
        if (another_board.isLegal(move))
        {
            temp_board_yo[move] = human;
            if (winner(temp_board_yo) == human)
            {
                cout << move << endl;
                return move;
            }
            // done checking this move, undo it
            temp_board_yo[move] = EMPTY;
        }
    }

    // the best moves to make, in order
    const int BEST_MOVES[] = { 4, 0, 2, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7 };
    // since no one can win on next move, pick best open square
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    {
        int move = BEST_MOVES[i];
        if (another_board.isLegal(move))
        {
            cout << move << endl;
            return move;
        }
    }
}
```

In my board cpp file I have

```
#include "tictactoe.h"

void Board::createBoard()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SQUARES; i++)
        board.push_back(' ');
}

void Board::displayBoard()
{
    cout << "\n\t" << board[0] << " | " << board[1] << " | " << board[2];
    cout << "\n\t" << "---------";
    cout << "\n\t" << board[3] << " | " << board[4] << " | " << board[5];
    cout << "\n\t" << "---------";
    cout << "\n\t" << board[6] << " | " << board[7] << " | " << board[8];
    cout << "\n\n";
}

void Board::insert(int temp_move,char temp_player)
{
    board[temp_move] = temp_player;
}

bool Board::isLegal(int move)
{
    return (board[move] ==' ');
}

vector <char> Board::getBoard()
{
    return board;
}
```

In my abstractplayer cpp file i have:

```
#include "tictactoe.h"

char Abstractplayer::askYesNo(string question)
{
    char response;
    do
    {
        cout << question << " (y/n): ";
        cin >> response;
    } while (response != 'y' && response != 'n');

    return response;
}
int Abstractplayer::askNumber(string question, int high, int low)
{
    int number;
    do
    {
        cout << question << " (" << low << " - " << high << "): ";
        cin >> number;
    } while (number > high || number < low);

    return number;
}
char Abstractplayer::winner(vector<char> const & another_temp_board)
{
    // all possible winning rows
    const int WINNING_ROWS[8][3] = { { 0, 1, 2 },
    { 3, 4, 5 },
    { 6, 7, 8 },
    { 0, 3, 6 },
    { 1, 4, 7 },
    { 2, 5, 8 },
    { 0, 4, 8 },
    { 2, 4, 6 } };
    const int TOTAL_ROWS = 8;

    // if any winning row has three values that are the same (and not EMPTY),
    // then we have a winner
    for (int row = 0; row < TOTAL_ROWS; ++row)
    {
        if ((another_temp_board[WINNING_ROWS[row][0]] != EMPTY) &&
            (another_temp_board[WINNING_ROWS[row][0]] == another_temp_board[WINNING_ROWS[row][1]]) &&
            (another_temp_board[WINNING_ROWS[row][1]] == another_temp_board[WINNING_ROWS[row][2]]))
        {
            return another_temp_board[WINNING_ROWS[row][0]];
        }
    }

    // since nobody has won, check for a tie (no empty squares left)
    if (count(another_temp_board.begin(), another_temp_board.end(), EMPTY) == 0)
        return TIE;

    // since nobody has won and it isn't a tie, the game ain't over
    return NO_ONE;
}
```

In my game_implementation cpp I have

```
#include "tictactoe.h"

void Game::instructions()
{
    cout << "Welcome to the ultimate man-machine showdown: Tic-Tac-Toe.\n";
    cout << "--where human brain is pit against silicon processor\n\n";

    cout << "Make your move known by entering a number, 0 - 8.  The number\n";
    cout << "corresponds to the desired board position, as illustrated:\n\n";

    cout << "       0 | 1 | 2\n";
    cout << "       ---------\n";
    cout << "       3 | 4 | 5\n";
    cout << "       ---------\n";
    cout << "       6 | 7 | 8\n\n";

    cout << "Prepare yourself, human.  The battle is about to begin.\n\n";
}

void Game::play()
{
    instructions();
    board.createBoard();

    while (Human->winner(board.getBoard()) =='N')
    {
        if (turn == Human->selectPiece())//Human goes 
        {

            //move = humanMove(board, human);
            move = Human->move(Human->selectPiece());
            board.insert(move, Human->selectPiece());
            turn = cpu->selectPiece();
        }
        else//Computer goes
        {
            //move = computerMove(board, computer);
            move = cpu->move(cpu->selectPiece());
            board.insert(move, cpu->selectPiece());
            turn = Human->selectPiece();
        }
        board.displayBoard();
    }

    announceWinner(cpu->winner(board.getBoard()), cpu->selectPiece(), Human->selectPiece());//error: says does not take 1 argument


}

void Game::announceWinner(char winner, char computer, char human)
{
    if (winner == computer)
    {
        cout << winner << "'s won!\n";
        cout << "As I predicted, human, I am triumphant once more -- proof\n";
        cout << "that computers are superior to humans in all regards.\n";
    }

    else if (winner == human)
    {
        cout << winner << "'s won!\n";
        cout << "No, no!  It cannot be!  Somehow you tricked me, human.\n";
        cout << "But never again!  I, the computer, so swear it!\n";
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "It's a tie.\n";
        cout << "You were most lucky, human, and somehow managed to tie me.\n";
        cout << "Celebrate... for this is the best you will ever achieve.\n";
    }
}
```

And in my test file I have

```
#include "tictactoe.h"

int main()
{
    Game g;

    g.play();
}
```

Comment: Probably it would be better to have the print out from the compiler.

Comment: You've posted here 259 lines of code. ***259 lines!*** I will be thoroughly surprised if anyone here on the network reads through all of this.

Comment: @burton0 I showed the error the compiler gives

Comment: You're using `Human` before it's declared

Comment: Farrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr too much code for an SO question. Fortunately the problem is clearly visible right at the top of the first file you posted.

Comment: I only have one error left after rearranging the classes in my header file. The error now lies in my game function but I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not know anything about `Human`, `Computer`, and `Board` when it processes the lines:

```
Human* Human;//error
Computer* cpu;//error
Board board;
```

You will need to add forward declarations of `Human` and `Computer` before the definition of `Game` since you are only declaring pointers to those types in `Game`.

You need to move the definition of `Board` before the definition of `Game` since you are declaring an object of that type in `Game`.

**P.S.** There may be other errors that need to be fixed too.

**Update**

```
while (Human->winner(& board.getBoard) =='N')
```

is not right since `board.getBoard` is member function. What you need there is:

```
while (Human->winner(board.getBoard()) =='N')
                                // ^^ Missing parens
```

However, for this to work, you'll need to change the interface of `Abstractplayer::winner` to

```
char winner(vector<char> another_temp_board)
```

or

```
char winner(vector<char> const& another_temp_board)
```

Comment: @R Sahu I reordered my classes in my header file and it got me alot less errors. I have one error in my game function which says error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression. Ill heighlight the error in my code

Comment: @user5001170, your error message says the file name is `game_implementation.cpp`. Your question does not have that file name.

Comment: @R Sahu I edited the question by including the game_implementation.cpp file code. Sorry for not including it before!

Comment: @R Sahu now my code compiles except it crashes as soon as I get to the menu. I also updated my code by fixing some other syntax issues that were similar to the one you were showing me

Comment: @user5001170, unfortunately, I won't be able to help you with that with so much code and so many files. You'll have to reduce the code size piece by piece and figure out where the problem is. Hopefully, that will give you enough information to fix it also.

Comment: @R Sahu I understand i shouldnt of asked you to check all the code because of that. However I think the issue still lies with
while (Human->winner(board.getBoard()) =='N')